# Pandas - cell values with a list of items

Tags: pandas

I have the following (simplified) dataframe, where rows are displayed player-wise:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'match_id':[123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 123],
                   'player_id':[1,1,1,2,2,2],
                   'position':['GKP','GKP','GKP','DEF','DEF','DEF']})
```

or:

```
   match_id  player_id position
0       123          1      GKP
1       123          1      GKP
2       123          1      GKP
3       123          2      DEF
4       123          2      DEF
5       123          2      DEF
```

---

Now I need to transform that into a match-wise rows dataframe, and crunch all other player data into a list of items, ending up with:

```
   match_id   from_1_to_11
0       123   [(1,GKP),(2,DEF)]
```

---

How do I do this with `pandas`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `unique`

```
out = df[['player_id','position']].agg(tuple,1).groupby(df['match_id']).unique()
Out[96]: 
match_id
123    [(1, GKP), (2, DEF)]
```

Comment: neat. what is 1 doing in `agg(tuple,1)`?

Comment: @8-Bit Borges this is a better answer. Should accept it! +1

Comment: the `1` in the agg function refers to the axis argument; the tuple is created column wise

Answer (score 2):

```
#First create a new column which concatenates two relevant columns into  tuples    
df=df.assign(from_1_to_11=tuple(zip(df.player_id,df.position))).drop(columns=['player_id','position'])

#Option1: Put it in a set
#print(df.groupby('match_id').agg(set))
 
#Option2: Put values in a list. You will have to tkae them to set to eliminate any duplicates
df.groupby('match_id').apply(lambda x: list(set(x['from_1_to_11']))).to_frame('from_1_to_11')



              from_1_to_11
match_id                      
123       [(2, DEF), (1, GKP)]
```